# How to Update Orientation in an XML File programmatiocally in onConfigurationChanged method?

Tags: android-layout

I have an xml file named activity_main:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"
 >
<fragment android:name="com.example.shko_00.myapp.MapsActivity"
    android:id="@+id/lm_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<fragment android:name="com.example.shko_00.myapp.GPSActivity"
 android:id="@+id/pm_fragment"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to ask, If there is any way for updating android:orientation from vertical to horizontal programmatically in  onConfigurationChanged method when the orientation changed to landscape?

Comment: Do you make some research before asking? It sound very common operation, so may be there are already examples how to do that on the Internet. Check how to ask question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Of course I did.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing orientation is not the right approach here. You should have another file your_layout_name-land. In that file use horizontal orientation.

Comment: I added another file activity_main_land.It works when the screen changed to land scape, but when it turned back to portrait the application not working.here is my code:     @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_land);
        }
       else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

Comment: You dont need any code in onConfigChange() if you have a different xml for landscape mode. Android will pick up the default xml which has vertical orientation when the device is in portrait mode

Comment: I have two fragments.The orientation in the xml file is vertical, therefore, the fragments are displayed from top to bottom. When the orientation is changed to landscape, fragments are remain in the same order. But I need to change their order from left to right(for doing this, the orientation needs to be changed into horizontal instead of vertical).So,I want to change the orientation to horizontal when the device in landscape mode. Does another xml file for landscape mode is needed? if yes, how to call this file? If not, how to change the vertical orientation from the xml file to horizontal?

Comment: Yes! Having a different xml is the proper way for doing what you want to achieve.If your current xml file's name is abc.xml your xml file with orientation set as horizontal should be named abc-land.xml.

Comment: Please read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for reference